# Spring Data Mongo: dropCollection doesn't remove collection completely?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Code:

```
template.dropCollection("products");
```

After code execution, I see that all documents from collection `products` were removed, but collection by itself still exists.

So, the question then is how to drop collection completely?

Note: spring-data-mongodb:2.2.10.RELEASE
Mongo DB 4.2.12.

Comment: How did you determine the collection still exists?

Comment: @Joe, Mongo  GUI tools like Roto3t or Studio 3T show that the `products` collection exists. And when I do execute `db.getCollectionNames()` command via Robo3t collection name is also available in the list. But when I do execute   template.getCollectionNames().forEach(System.out::println) it shows that collection removed, so I confused how even it is possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a refresh button when you use MongoDB Compass.
[image: MongoDB Compass]

Check the collection names, it is already dropped.

```
System.out.println(template.getCollectionNames());
template.dropCollection("products");
System.out.println(template.getCollectionNames());
```